# Displaying value of one cell or multiple cells based on values in other cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that lists a bunch of names and we are keeping track of how many times a certain occurrence happens. What I'm needing to do is find a way to calculate which name has the highest value of occurrences, and then display that name in another cell. What I'd also like to do, is if there is a tie, I'd like to display all of the names of the people who are in the tie for 1st. Any assistance is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you familiar with VBA or are you better with formulas? If you show your efforts so far, you're more likely to get help. :)

Comment: Thank you Zairja. I apologize I am not familiar with VBA and I am better with formulas. All of my thought process in my formulas I haven't tried because I know they won't do what I'm looking to do. I realize I'm trying to do something I don't have the know-how for yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Advanced Filter` feature to do this:

(Screen shot from Excel 2010)

[image]

Formula in cell `B2:  =COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)` (copy down as raf as required)

Formula in cell `D2: =MAX(B:B)`

Click OK and highest count names will be listed in column `F` (`t` and `y` in this example)

Comment: Thank you Chris. This works great. Just out of curiousity, is there a way to do this where it will update real time? For instance, if I add another t to your example, it will still display t and y under names as the two having the most.